# ANOVA assumptions by subsets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, assumptions

Assesing (with R) the assumptions for normality and homogeneity of my variables for an ANOVA:

Should I run one normality and homogeneity test to each of the 3 subset of variables got after splitting into treatments? 
It alls means 12 tests (3 for normality for both x and y; 3 for normality for both x and y)

Thanks so much

Comment: Start with the homogeneity test. If this passes, then test for normality with the data sets combined (though you may want to mean center first within each group first).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but "with the data sets combined", do you mean 12 tests? Should it make sense to do it only at the end for the residuals?

Comment: You only need the residuals to be normally distributed, not the actual values. As for the combination (aggregation) of data sets, you would only combine the data sets for the same variable (e.g., combine the x's, combine the y's, but don't combine the two sets together).